# DNS txt record invalid packet, FORMERR

Tags: dns

I'm having trouble with my home made "for fun" nameserver. It's been a couple of months since I updated it so I'm a bit rusty and thought I'd ask here and see if someone else sees what's wrong. I'm getting a FORMERR when asking for a TXT record, and the same problem occur on different domains, so there's probably something wrong in the packet formatting. Anyone?

```
dig txt ffffff.com @ns1.ffffff.com
;; Got bad packet: FORMERR
1024 bytes
ce bf 84 00 00 01 00 01 00 02 00 00 06 66 66 66          .............fff
66 66 66 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 10 00 01 c0 0c 00 10          fff.com.........
00 01 00 00 02 58 00 13 12 57 65 6c 63 6f 6d 65          .....X...Welcome
20 74 6f 20 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 00 c0 0c 00 02          .to.fffffff.....
00 01 00 00 02 58 00 10 03 6e 73 31 06 66 66 66          .....X...ns1.fff
66 66 66 03 63 6f 6d 00 c0 0c 00 02 00 01 00 00          fff.com.........
02 58 00 10 03 6e 73 32 06 66 66 66 66 66 66 03          .X...ns2.ffffff.
63 6f 6d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          com.............
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example above supplied, I added an incorrect 00 (null terminator) at the end of the TXT-string. After removing the null terminator from the TXT records, the txt records now work on my nameserver.